# Android edit text doesn't change after screen rotates

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I started working on Android recently and have been trying to use the new Andorid Jetpack Architecture approach to making my app. Specificly, i saw that usually they use a ViewModel to store the UI data, so that when stuff like screen rotations happen, the data dosen't get lost. I have a simple Login Screen with two Edit Text fields, when i write something in them, then rotate the screen, the data stays. So bassicly the questions are:

- Why don't i lose the data from the Edit Text's
- When should i use this ViewModel stuff. Do people use it in simple situations like a basic log in screen where you just have two strings, or is it only used in larger activities.
- I have the same question about these LifeCycle observers. I know how they work, but should i use them in simple situations like the one mentioned above, or is it better to just use these things in more complex situations, since i don't really know what to do for my basic log in screen other than the basic stuff in OnCreate() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this image to understand the lifecycle of the ViewModel and why your `EditText` data is not lost.

[image: ViewModel Lifecycle]

You should learn about MVVM pattern (Model View Viewmodel) to understand how to use the `ViewModel`. Take a look at this [CodeLabs from Google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0).

[image: MVVM pattern]